# Javascript beginner - global variable isnt working

Tags: javascript, json, variables

I want to give out the value (defined in function getInfo) of the global var "title" but all i get at the alert(title) is "undefined". Sure i can put the alert in the last function but why i doesnt work this way?

```
//[...]
var title;//global var

$(document).ready(
function(){                    
    $.getJSON(url, displayImages)//open func displayImages
});

function displayImages(data) {                                                                                                                                              
    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function(i,item){
            $.getJSON(url+item.id+"&format=json&jsoncallback=?", getInfo);//open func getInfo
            alert(title);//output: undefined

    });     

}

function getInfo(data2){
    title = data2.photo.title._content;//get value of title from json

}
```

Comment: the reason is `alert(title)` is being executed before `getInfo`. why because `getJSON` spends some time to fetch data but and while its doing `alert(title)` is being executed, thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous, which means that if you put an alert in the `getInfo` method, it would fire *after* the `alert(title)` even though it is a line before it.

You could fix this as such:

```
$.getJSON(url+item.id+"&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data) { 
  getInfo(data);
  alert(title);
});
```